# How to modify this script to get only the mp4 file version from youtube knowing the youtube id?

Tags: php, youtube

How to mofify this to get only the url of the mp4 file version?

```
<?php

//$debug = true;

if(empty($debug))
    $debug = false;

if(empty($_GET['id']))
    die('no id');
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9-_]+$/i', $_GET['id']))
    die('invalid character in id');
else
    $id = $_GET['id'];

if(empty($_GET['type']))
    $type = 'mp4';
else
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Z]+$/i', $_GET['type']))
    die('invalid character in type');
else
    $type = strtolower($_GET['type']);


$url = 'http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=';
$key = 'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map';
$content = file_get_contents($url.$id);
parse_str($content, $result);

if($debug)
    {
    echo $url.$id.'<br/>';
    echo $key.'<br/>';
    echo $type.'<br/>';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
else
    {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="videofile.'.$type.'"');
    }

$type = 'type=video/'.$type;
$files = explode(',url=', $result[$key]);
$files[0] = substr($files[0], 4);

for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
    $file = urldecode($files[$i]);
    $found = strpos($file, $type) > -1;

    if ($debug)
        {
        if ($found) 
            echo '[THIS]';
        echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br/><br/>';
        }
    else
        {
        if ($found) 
            {
            $file = explode('; codecs=', $file);
            @readfile($file[0]);
            break;
            }
        }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do a redirect instead of a readfile. I suspect that's against youtube's TOS anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 3 links are all the mp4 links with different ID tages (at the end).
Itags are different HD/Normal formats for the screen resolution, Google them up.
However, if you want to land now, keep this:

```
<?php

$debug = true;

if(empty($debug))
    $debug = false;

if(empty($_GET['id']))
    die('no id');
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9-_]+$/i', $_GET['id']))
    die('invalid character in id');
else
    $id = $_GET['id'];

if(empty($_GET['type']))
    $type = 'mp4';
else
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Z]+$/i', $_GET['type']))
    die('invalid character in type');
else
    $type = strtolower($_GET['type']);


$url = 'http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=';
$key = 'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map';
$content = file_get_contents($url.$id);
parse_str($content, $result);

/*if($debug)
    {
    echo $url.$id.'<br/>';
    echo $key.'<br/>';
    echo $type.'<br/>';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
else
    {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="videofile.'.$type.'"');
    }
*/
$type = 'type=video/'.$type;
$files = explode(',url=', $result[$key]);
$files[0] = substr($files[0], 4);

for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
    $file = urldecode($files[$i]);
    $found = strpos($file, $type) > -1;
    $itag = strpos($file, "itag=18") > -1;

        if ($found & $itag){
        echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$debug = true;

if(empty($debug))
    $debug = false;

if(empty($_GET['id']))
    die('no id');
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9-_]+$/i', $_GET['id']))
    die('invalid character in id');
else
    $id = $_GET['id'];

if(empty($_GET['type']))
    $type = 'mp4';
else
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Z]+$/i', $_GET['type']))
    die('invalid character in type');
else
    $type = strtolower($_GET['type']);


$url = 'http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=';
$key = 'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map';
$content = file_get_contents($url.$id);
parse_str($content, $result);

/*if($debug)
    {
    echo $url.$id.'<br/>';
    echo $key.'<br/>';
    echo $type.'<br/>';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
else
    {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="videofile.'.$type.'"');
    }
*/
$type = 'type=video/'.$type;
$files = explode(',url=', $result[$key]);
$files[0] = substr($files[0], 4);

for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
    $file = urldecode($files[$i]);
    $found = strpos($file, $type) > -1;

        if ($found){
        echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you but this is returning 3 links.